# Hibernate multi-app environment. Delete one child object if parent has multiple children

Tags: java, hibernate, struts, cascade

Hibernate 4.1 with XML mappings, Struts 1.3, multi-app environment sharing the same database. Let's say we have three tables:

```
Client          Car_Client           House_Client
------          ----------           ------------
id              client_id            client_id
name            date_purchased       date_purchased
```

The 3 mapping files:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <joined-subclass name="CarClient" extends="Client" table="Car_Client">
        <key column="client_id" />
        <property name="datePurchased">
            <column name="date_purchased" />
        </property>
    </joined-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <joined-subclass name="HouseClient" table="House_Client">
        <key column="client_id" />
        <property name="datePurchased">
            <column name="date_purchased" />
        </property>
    </joined-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Client is the parent object and the two applications(Car and House) share the parent table but each have their own subclass of the parent table to store extra information about the client. Each Hibernate mapping and Java class is extending the parent object.

So in normal use, when the Car app deletes a CarClient, the parent object is also deleted as usually a client exists in only one app. Sometimes though, a client may exist in both apps. Deleting that client from one app will remove the record from the child table and throw a ConstraintViolationException on the parent table.

Our solution is deleting the child record with an SQL query as HQL would try to delete the parent. We then have to refresh the cache so Hibernate knows the child record no longer exists.

Is there a way in Java to tell Hibernate to only delete the child record? Basically override the built-in behavior that deletes the parent object? Without having to write a custom query? May not be possible but I am curious if I'm missing something.

Comment: I think it will be difficult to understand what is going on without the XML mappings for the above entities

Comment: Created a mapping to help illustrate what I'm trying to do